# In SQL server, TOP is returning unexpected rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a table of Employees. It has EmployeeName (varchar(100)) and Salary field (deciaml). All the records are in sorted order, and I was trying to fetch records from 11th Employee to 20 Employee. I know there are multiple and simple ways to get this data and I've also done it with 3-4 different ways. But, one of the way that I tried is not working and it retruns unexpected data. Below are the scripts that I'm using:

Data script:

```
declare @counter int = 1
while(@counter <= 50)
begin
    insert into Employee (name,salary)  select CONCAT('name - ',@counter),100*@counter;
    set @counter += 1;
end

Select * from Employee
```

Query to fetch records:

```
select top(10) * from (
Select Top(20)* from Employee
) as t order by t.id desc
```

Explanation: First, I'm getting records of first 20 employees, using TOP(20). Then, I'm trying to order the data of 20 Employee in descending order and then get TOP(10) employees. It supposed ot return me Employee from 11-20 (in any order descinduing or ascinding). But, it returns employees from 50-41. Why?

Comment: You don't say any order in the inner query. It may return any 20 items.

Comment: Never use TOP without ORDER BY.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks Sami, now I get it what's wrong with my query.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Thank you Thorsten, for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TOP` without `ORDER BY` returns indeterminate rows.  You need the `ORDER BY` in the subquery as well as the outer query:

```
select top(10) e.*
from (Select Top(20) e.*
      from Employee e
      order by t.id asc
     ) e
order by e.id desc;
```

Your questions contains this:  "All the records are in sorted order".  That has no meaning in a relational database.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Result sets are only ordered when you use `ORDER BY`.

Note:  The use of clustered indexes does impose an ordering on the physical storage of the records in a table.  On a single processor machine (or a query that uses a single thread of execution), the results *in practice* are returned according to ordering of the clustered keys.  However, you should still not rely on that behavior, and use an explicit `ORDER BY` when you care about the ordering.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this is what I was looking for. Small modification in your query, instead descending order if I use Ascending order then it produces expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2012, why not just use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee e
ORDER BY e.id
OFFSET  10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thanks Cameron, but I already have working query. What I am looking for is reason for not working of my above mentioned query.